# Pixel doubling on 4K Monitor - Mouse, general UI laggy

Tags: display, pi-4

I'm trying to use a 4K monitor with a Raspi 4 B rev 1.2, so far I was able to find out that I need to use the pixel doubling in --> Preferences: Raspberry Pi Configuration: Pixel Doubling
Once that setting is applied the UI and specially the mouse starts showing some heavy lagging.
Is this something to expect or there's some kind of workaround for this behaviour?

Comment: Isn't it possible to just set the resolution at 2K instead of using pixel doubling?  Or you need it at 4K for other things?

Comment: Well actually I would like to use the full pixel capability of the screen to see the UI elements and content more sharply rendered.

Comment: But pixel doubling doesn't do that.  What you end up with is a 2K image on a 4K screen. That doesn't make it sharper. If there's any difference at all appearance wise, it's going to be worse using pixel doubling, way more error/problem prone, and expensive since this is a pure software solution to a problem that is better solved with existing capabilities of the hardware.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, the thing is that I've tried setting the resolution to 2K@60hz and that doesn't look very good either....